# Delphi TJvDBGrid save layout

Tags: delphi, jedi

I have a TJvDBGrid where I give the user the option to select the columns they want to display through the "TjvDBGrid.ShowColumnsDialog" command,
but I wanted to save this configuration so that next time I open the form, only the selected columns are displayed, I did not find anything on the subject, not even on the component page, I tried to use the component "JvAppIniFileStorage1" and "JvFormStorage1", but without success, how can I do this?

Comment: Did you try using the grid's `Columns.SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile` methods?

Comment: It worked, I thought it only worked with the default delphi grid, omg! thanks!